# Facing issue with the headless mode of chrome execution through webdriverIO

Tags: javascript, chromium, webdriver-io, google-chrome-headless, wdio

Facing issue with the headless mode of chrome execution through webdriverIO.

**Problem statement:**

I'm using custom chrome profile to bypass login to launch application and reached to homepage of an application. For that I've configured custom chrome profile configuration in my wdio.conf.ts file like below:

```
capabilities: [{
    maxInstances: 5,
    browserName: 'chrome',
    'goog:chromeOptions': {
      args: [
        'user-data-dir=/Users/dhrumilsoni/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/',
        'profile-directory=Profile 3',
        'headless'
      ]
    },
    acceptInsecureCerts: true
  }]
```

When I'm executing my spec file through headed mode of chrome browser, my test successfully executed. But when I tried to do with headless configuration with latest wdio version- my test got failed.

ERROR

```
[chrome 113.0.5672.126 mac os x #0-0] element ("//p[normalize-space()="ADD"]") still not displayed after 15000ms
```

Does headless chrome not supporting default user-data-directory path?

Need assistance in resolving the issue. Thanks.!!